# Power off the monitor on install Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, nvidia, 13.04, display, monitor

When i try to install Ubuntu 13.04 , I have problem to display .

In first i see the page same as blank after about 5 sec monitor power off and get to standby mode but the dvd-rom is worked hard and system too .

My monitor is LG Flatron E1940 and my Graphic cart is on-board and my main-board is [Asus M3N-HT Deluxe](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M3NHT_DeluxeHDMI/) .

what is the problem? 
How I can fix it and install Ubuntu 13.04 on my system ? ( because I can't install this without display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I press F6 before power off monitor and add command line to install -> `xforcevesa` and bypass my display VGA and install Ubuntu good.